# Unexpected result when passing datetime objects to str.format()

Tags: python, datetime

In Python 2.7, `str.format()` accepts non-string arguments and calls the `__str__` method of the value before formatting output:

```
class Test:
     def __str__(self):
         return 'test'

t = Test()
str(t) # output: 'test'
repr(t) # output: '__main__.Test instance at 0x...'

'{0: <5}'.format(t) # output: 'test ' in python 2.7 and TypeError in python3
'{0: <5}'.format('a') # output: 'a    '
'{0: <5}'.format(None) # output: 'None ' in python 2.7 and TypeError in python3
'{0: <5}'.format([]) # output: '[]   ' in python 2.7 and TypeError in python3
```

But when I pass a `datetime.time` object, I get `' <5'` as output in both Python 2.7 and Python 3:

```
from datetime import time
'{0: <5}'.format(time(10,10)) # output: ' <5'
```

Passing a `datetime.time` object to `str.format()` should either raise a `TypeError` or format `str(datetime.time)`, instead it returns the formatting directive. Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`'{0: <5}'.format(time(10, 10))` results in call to `time(10, 10).__format__`, which returns `<5` for the `<5` format specifier:

```
In [26]: time(10, 10).__format__(' <5')
Out[26]: ' <5'
```

This happens because [`time_instance.__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.__format__) attempts to format `time_instance` using [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.strftime) and `time.strftime` doesn't understand the formatting directive.

```
In [29]: time(10, 10).strftime(' <5')
Out[29]: ' <5'
```

---

The `!s` conversion flag will tell `str.format` to call `str` on the `time` instance before rendering the result - it will call `str(time(10, 10)).__format__(' <5')`:

```
In [30]: '{0!s: <5}'.format(time(10, 10))
Out[30]: '10:10:00'
```

Comment: You didn't provide an answer to my question; so have to upvote elsewhere ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`datetime` objects support the `datetime.strftime()` options when formatting:

```
>>> from datetime import time
>>> '{0:%H}'.format(time(10,10))
'10'
```

That format includes support for literal text:

```
>>> time(10, 10).strftime('Hour: %H')
'Hour: 10'
```

The `>5` format is treated as literal text. You can fit your time into a 5-character column using the following format:

```
'{0:%H:%M}'
```